# relationship between page table size, patge table entry and pagt table base register alignment

Tags: computer-architecture, virtual-memory

I am trying to understand this question from Prof. Onur Mutlu's [assignment solution](http://course.ece.cmu.edu/%7Eece447/s15/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=hw4_s15_sol.pdf) on virtual memory.

I am reproducing the problem and solution followed by my question:
Problem: A dedicated computer architecture student (like you) bought a 32-bit processor that implements paging-based virtual memory using a single-level page table. Being a careful person, she also read the manual and learnt that

- A page table entry (PTE) is 4-bytes in size.
- A PTE stores the physical page number in the least-significant bits.
- Unused bits are zeroed out.
- The page table base address (PTBA) is page-aligned.
- If an instruction attempts to modify a PTE, an exception is raised.

However, the manual did not mention the page size and the PTBA. The dedicated student then wrote the following program to find out the missing information.
char *ptr = 0xCCCCCCCC;
˚ptr = 0x00337333;
The code ran with no exceptions. The following figure shows relevant locations of the physical memory after execution. (Figure as well.) I reproduced he figure here, since previous so's users discourage posting images. [image: attached]

31..................0 0xFFFFFFFF

0x00337333     0xCDCCCCCC

0x00337333     0xCCCCCCCC

0x00337333     0x00000000
Using these results, what is the PTBA of this machine?

Solution:
Let n = log2(page size).
Maximum possible number of unused bits in a PTE is 10. This means n ď 10.

```
max. possible number of unused bits is 10 is arrived upon by looking at PTE entry, and since both the entries have MSB's as 0x003 or 0b0000_0000_0011_... is this observation leading to conclusion that n <= 10?
```

0xC = 0b1100
If n % 4 == 0 => PTE offset ends with 0b110000, PTBA is not page aligned.
If n % 4 == 1 => PTE offset ends with 0b11000, PTBA is not page aligned.
If n % 4 == 2 => PTE offset ends with 0b1100, PTBA is aligned.
If n % 4 == 3 => PTE offset ends with 0b110, PTBA is not page aligned.
This leaves 10, 6, 2 as the only possible values of n.

```
how % 4 of page size leads to LSB's of PTE offset and secondly, how LSB's of PTE offset leads to conclusion on PTBA alignment?
what is PTE offset. is VPN (VA >> n) called PTE offset or (VA >>n) x 4 (4 because each PTE entry is 4B) called PTE offset?
```

Since all relevant memory locations are shown, the write must have occured to one of the two entries. However, neither n = 2 or or n = 6 results in a physical address that maps to the two locations.

```
how did they arrive upon at the conclusion that n = 2 or 6 results in a physical address that doesn't maps to the two locations shown?
```

This leaves n = 10.
Now suppose if 0xCDCCCCCC was PTE. Translating to physical address leads to 0xCDCCCCCC again. This would have triggered an exception.
This means 0xCCCCCCCC was the PTE, and the value was written to 0xCDCCCCCC.
Using this information, PTBA = 0xCCCCCCCC - (0x333333<<2) = 0xCC000000.